# git: Can a commit object have no author/committer?

Tags: git

I need to parse author and committer identities from commits.

Now I wondered if it is possible to have commits that don't have an `author` or `committer` (or both) set. My first thought was that this would probably be illegal, and there can't be a case where it is not set, but I'm not sure if that's true.

Is an author/committer always required or is there a case in which any of them might not be set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A commit that lacks author or committer is malformed and will be diagnosed by `git fsck`.  That doesn't mean that you might not ever *encounter* one, but if you do, it's definitely wrong.

Oddly, a quick eyeball scan of [`fsck.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e19713638985533ce461db072b49112da5bd2042/fsck.c#L854-L908) shows that `git fsck` also rejects any commit with more than one author, but appears to allow more than one committer.  Note the counting of author lines, and the lack of counting of committer lines.  I have not observed any commits with multiple author or committer lines, but [commit `c9ad147f83f70b6add9066e16e1e44c8bc3d5c13`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9ad147f83f70b6add9066e16e1e44c8bc3d5c13) mentions specifically that multiple author lines have occurred, and splits out the counting so that this particular error can be configured to demote it to a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [link](https://github.community/t/why-is-my-commit-associated-with-the-wrong-person/10199):

> If you don’t specify any authors, the user.name and user.email from
> your local Git configuration will be used by default

Regarding the committer:

> The  committer  is the person who most recently applied a set of changes. You’re probably familiar with applying changes by creating a commit, using git commit while working locally. In this case, the author and the committer are usually the same person.

> ...
> When you work on GitHub.com, you’re the author, but GitHub (GitHub noreply@github.com) is the committer. You make the changes, and we apply them for you behind the scenes.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. The question is if it is technically possible to have an empty author/committer on a git object.